# Why this lines aren't working?

Tags: javascript

My question is how to put this:

```
function setTextColor(picker) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('agario-panel')[0].style.color = '#' + picker.toString()
```

In html and this:

```
panelPlusK.append("<button class="jscolor {valueElement:'chosen-value', onFineChange:'setTextColor(this)'}">Pick Menu Color </button>");
```

I tried with jquery but when I put one of that two codes, the js file dosen't load.

Here is my code:

```
$( "div" ).remove( ".ogario-yt-panel" );
$( "div" ).remove( "#ogario-ad" );
$( "div" ).remove( "#version" );
$( "h2" ).remove( ".main-color" );
$( "h1" ).remove();
$( "#s300x250" ).remove();
$( "#socialStats" ).replaceWith('<div id="socialStats" style="position: absolute;bottom: 70px;left: 25px;right:25px;"><button id="gPlusShare" style="width:49%;float:left;display:none" class="g-interactivepost btn btn-primary btn-gplus" data-contenturl="http://agar.io" data-clientid="" data-cookiepolicy="http://agar.io" data-prefilltext="" data-calltoactionlabel="BEAT" data-calltoactionurl="http://agar.io"><span class="gplus-icon"></span><span class="btn-text" data-itr="share">Share</span></button><button id="fbShare" class="btn btn-primary btn-fb" onclick="fbShareStats(); return false" style="position:relative;width:49%;float:left;"><span class="social social-facebook fb-icon"></span><span class="btn-text" data-itr="share">Share</span></button><button class="btn btn-primary btn-twitter" onclick="twitterShareStats(); return false" style="position:relative;width:49%;float:right"><span class="twitter-icon"></span><span class="btn-text" data-itr="share">Share</span></button></div>');
$( "#statsContinue" ).replaceWith('<button id="statsContinue" class="btn btn-primary" data-itr="continue">Continue</button>')
$("#mainPanel").before('<div id="harryext" style="/* background-color: rgba(133, 58, 182, 0); */margin-top: 2px;width: 340px;margin-left: 4px;border-bottom: 2.5px solid #ff0202;font-size: 25px;padding: 5px;font-weight: 600;color: #E91E63;margin-bottom: 7px;" align="center">HarrY ExT</div>');
$( "#leaderboard-hud h4" ).replaceWith( "<div class='header'>HarrYExt V.1</div>" );
$( "div" ).remove( "#leaderboard-hud" );
$(".party-panel").after('<div id="PrivateServersPanel" class="agario-panel agario-side-panel"><select id="PrivateServer" class="form-control privateServer" style="height: 35px; display: block; width: 100%; float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;"><option value="Private Servers" disabled="" default="" selected="" style="display: none;width:100%">Private Servers</option><option value="ws://parisgamma.iomods.com:1501">Private Party</option><option value="ws://82.11.47.60:443">Private Party (2)</option><option value="ws://185.38.150.94:443">W = Virus</option><option value="ws://vps56296.vps.ovh.ca:443">Huge Map + SelfFeed</option><option value="ws://vps62061.vps.ovh.ca:443">Juggernaut Mode</option><option value="ws://ffa1.unnamedcell.com:443">Unlimited Split</option><option value="ws://agario.willsr71.net:8080">Fast Merge</option></select><button class="btn btn-nosx joinPrivate1" style="height:35px;margin-bottom: 10px;width:100%;" onclick="$(\'.partyToken\').val($(\'#PrivateServer\').val()); connect($(\'#PrivateServer\').val());">Connect</button></div>');

$("#mainPanel").after('<div align="middle" id="Radio" class="RadioClass" style="display: block;width: 90%;margin-left: 16px;margin-top: 2px;"><audio style="width:100%;" controls="" src="http://192.99.0.170:5529/;"><a href="music.html" target="radio" align="middle"></a></audio></div>');
$("title").replaceWith('<title>HarryExT</title>');

$("#PrivateServersPanel").after('<div id="addMenuKontainer" class="agario-panel agario-side-panel" style="margin-bottom:0px !important"><div class="clear-menu-btnK"><input id="addMenuK" type="checkbox"><span class="topK"></span><span class="middleK"></span><span class="bottomK"></span><span class="circleK"></span></div><p style="text-align:center;color:#42A5F5">Some Options</p></div>');
$("#addMenuKontainer").after('<div id="additionalPanelK" class="agario-panel agario-side-panel" style="margin-top:0px;display:none;padding-top:0px !important;font-size:12px !important;font-family:Ubuntu"></div>');
$("#addMenuK").on("click",function(){
    $("#additionalPanelK").toggle();
});

//Additional Settings Checks
var panelPlusK = $("#additionalPanelK");
var stSett = $(".col-xs-6.firstSettings");
panelPlusK.append("<br><input id='opt_privateServer' type='checkbox'> Hide Private Servers<br>");
var privatePanelK = $("#PrivateServersPanel");

if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("opt_privateServer"))===true){
    $("#opt_privateServer").prop("checked",true);
    privatePanelK.hide();
} else if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("opt_privateServer"))===false){
    $("#opt_privateServer").prop("checked",false);
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("opt_privateServer",false);
}
$("#opt_privateServer").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        privatePanelK.hide();
        localStorage.setItem("opt_privateServer",true);
    } else {
        privatePanelK.show();
        localStorage.setItem("opt_privateServer",false);
    }
});

panelPlusK.append("<input id='opt_radioK' type='checkbox'> Hide Radio<br>");

if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("opt_radioK"))===true){
    $("#opt_radioK").prop("checked",true);
    $("#Radio").hide();
} else if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("opt_radioK"))===false){
    $("#opt_radioK").prop("checked",false);
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("opt_radioK",false);
}
$("#opt_radioK").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $("#Radio").hide();
        localStorage.setItem("opt_radioK",true);
    } else {
        $("#Radio").show();
        localStorage.setItem("opt_radioK",false);
    }

});
```

When I add those two things the page dosen't load the js file.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML you are using?

Comment: what kind of a title is that? please change it to a proper title

Comment: `function setTextColor(picker) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('agario-panel')[0].style.color = '#' + picker.toString()
        function setTextColor(picker) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('agario-panel')[0].style.color = '#' + picker.toString()`    should be   ->     `function setTextColor(picker) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('agario-panel')[0].style.color = '#' + picker.toString();
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that this:

```
panelPlusK.append("<button class="jscolor {valueElement:'chosen-value', onFineChange:'setTextColor(this)'}">Pick Menu Color </button>");
```

Is not valid javascript.

If you need to have quotes inside of other quotes, you must escape them (instead of `"`, use `\"`). So give this a try:

```
panelPlusK.append("<button class=\"jscolor {valueElement:'chosen-value', onFineChange:'setTextColor(this)'}\">Pick Menu Color </button>");
```

**UPDATE:**

Additionally, it looks like this bit of code:

```
function setTextColor(picker) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('agario-panel')[0].style.color = '#' + picker.toString()
```

needs a closing bracket (and I think you should be using `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementsByTagName`), like this:

```
function setTextColor(picker) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('agario-panel')[0].style.color = '#' + picker.toString();
}
```

That might solve your second problem (referred to in the comment on this answer) - but if not, I would recommend adding some `console.log()` statements above the bit of code that is not working, try this:

```
function setTextColor(picker) {
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('agario-panel')[0]);
  console.log('#' + picker.toString());
  document.getElementsByTagName('agario-panel')[0].style.color = '#' + picker.toString();
}
```

And then look in your developer console (`cmd + shift + j` in chrome on mac) and check the logs. You should see two, the first with the element in question, and the second with the color you are trying to set.

If you are not seeing what you expect, you can use that information to debug.

Comment: thanks it worked :) but i have new problem   :: function setTextColor(picker) { document.getElementsByClassName('agario-panel')[0].style.color = '#' + picker.toString(); }   dosent change the color of class agario-panel

Comment: the element is this one : `.agario-panel {
    background-color: rgba(64, 86, 103, 0.42);
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}`

Comment: Oh, I think you need to use `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementsByTagName`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: this time it show me this :                                                            `<div class="agario-panel offerwall" style="color: rgb(102, 97, 255);">
<div style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 4px;">
<button type="button" class="close" onclick="closeOfferwall(); return false;">×</button>
</div>
<div id="offerwallIframeWrapper">
<iframe id="offerwallIframe" frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>
</div>
</div>`                                                                                                 but the color of the panel dosent change ..dont knw why

Comment: Setting `style.color =` will only change the text color, it looks like you do not have any text there, I think you want to use `style.backgroundColor =`

Comment: yeah i knw and i change it but nothing ..it show me the same thing ... don't knw what to do ..i u want u can install the script using tempermonkey this: http://gdriv.es/harryxz/omod.user.js   and after go to agar.io and try it :) thanks for your help